# Webservice configuration WFC 400 Error (large Request)

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf, wcf-binding

I have a problem and hope anyone can help me. I use a windows application (Visual Studio 2010) with webservice an try to transfer more than 1200 dataobjekt in a list form the WS to win. But i get a WCF 400 Error und don’t now what else I can change or what can be wrong.
(smaller request are ok)

```
WIN: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="F*******" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="myBehavior">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483646"/>
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding closeTimeout="00:20:00" openTimeout="00:20:00" sendTimeout="00:20:00"
          maxBufferSize="2147483646" 
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483646">
          <readerQuotas 
            maxDepth="2147483646" 
            maxStringContentLength="2147483646"
            maxArrayLength="2147483646" 
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483646" 
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483646" />
        </binding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService1" />
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <client>
      <clear />
      <endpoint address="http://*******/Service1.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="myBehavior" contract="******.IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_IService11" />  
    </client>

  </system.serviceModel>


  <appSettings>
    <add key="Standort" value="6" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>

WS:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
        <behavior name="myNetTcpBehaviour">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding
          name="BasicHttpBindingSettings"
          transferMode="Streamed"
          closeTimeout="00:10:00"
          openTimeout="00:10:00"
          sendTimeout="00:10:00"
          maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647"
          maxBufferSize="2147483647"
          messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <readerQuotas
            maxDepth="2147483647"
            maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647"
            maxBytesPerRead="2147483647"
            maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="FachlService.IService1">
        <endpoint contract="FachlService.IService1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBindingSettings" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <compilation debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

I really hop for some help... thanks :-)

Comment: It looks like you covered the request size and the max items. Are you retuning the data on the query string by chance? Also, may need to check <httpRuntime maxRequestLength=""/>

Comment: Also, shouldn't it be maxBufferPoolSize for the binding? You may want to add a receiveTimeout on the binding to allow longer reads.